# Frontend conditionally open download dialog or display error

Tags: javascript

Given the following expressjs server code which conditionally responses to the same entry point, I want to display error  message or open download dialog based on server's response. It possible and if so, what i s a recommended way to do it?

```js
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
  if (conditionA) {
    return res.status(403).send({err: 'Message I want to display with frontend JS'});
  } else {
    return res.sendFile('file I want to  send');
  }
});
```

Comment: Depends on how request is made. Not enough known

Comment: @charlietfl Currently I simply use `<a href='/download'>Link</a>`. But I think it should be changed, but I don't know how it should be changed.

Comment: for that case you need to render a page

Comment: @charlietfl So what you're saying is to replace `res.status(403).send(something)` to `res.render('errorPage', {err: 'blah'})`?

Comment: Yes... can also set status as well to prevent seo indexing